# Select SQL Query referencing Worksheet Index

Tags: sql, excel, database

I have set up excel as a database as part of a larger automation project I am working on, i have the following SQL select query which works as expected.

I have a new task to extract data from a worksheet where the worksheet name is not known however i can reference the worksheet index. Can anyone advise what syntax is required to reference a worksheet index.

Current statement I am using:

```
  SELECT * FROM [Report 1$]
```

- Report 1$ being the sheetname which in some cases may not be known

Answer (score 0):

short answer is no , you can't do that  but the workaround this problem is to get the sheets name dynamically, there is good solution here

[Get Excel sheet name In SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439068/get-excel-sheet-name-in-sql-server)